# Do we have to write the content of the fos_user_content when extending the layout?

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hello I'm trying to use a custom form for a user registration:
In my layout.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'ProjectBundle::project.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

It displays the form correctly.

Now I want to customize the login page : 
I create a Security/login.html.twig

The content is :

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
```

But it doesn't display the form.
Any idea why ?

Comment: I don't know why, but this just reminds me of the $scope problem in AngularJs , but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with that problematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I would organize things :

In app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'MVPBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then, if you want to custom the login page, for instance, you put in app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig (same architecture as in the vendor fosuser) :

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

{# Your overriding template of the login view (containing the essential lines taken from the fox user view of the vendor, especially the ones displaying the form #}

{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

So my guess is that you may have forgotten these "essential" lines displaying the form in your own login template

You can find more about that here :
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

I hope it will help you... :)